# Classification of 2-periodic triangulated categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Let $T$ be an algebraic triangulated (k-linear over a field, Hom-finite, idempotent-complete) category. Call $T$ 2-periodic if $\Omega^2(X) \cong X$ for all $X \in T$.

> Question 1: Is there a classification of such 2-periodic triangulated categories?

> Question 2: Is it known for which (commutative local noetherian) Gorenstein rings all maximal Cohen-Macaulay modules are 2-periodic?

> Question 3: Is there an explicit classification of such 2-periodic triangulated categories with only finitely many indecomposable objects?

Here by explicit is meant an explicit list of quiver and relations for the stable Auslander algebras of finite 2-periodic triangulated categories, which contain for example preprojective algebras of Dynkin type.

Comment: Do you assume that the equivalence $\Omega^2X\simeq X$ is functorial?

Comment: @Z.M No, but if it helps, one can assume that.